# Convert even parity ASCII to normal ASCII

Tags: c#, ascii

I have a byte array:

```
evenParityASCII[0] = 0xB1; // 1
evenParityASCII[1] = 0xB2; // 2
evenParityASCII[2] = 0x33; // 3
evenParityASCII[3] = 0xB4; // 4
evenParityASCII[4] = 0x35; // 5
```

I need to convert these to normal ASCII. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean like `for(int i=0;i<evenParityASCII.Count;i++){ evenParityASCII[i] &= AND 0x7F; }`?

Comment: Usually the hardware takes care of parity for you. Do you have a mismatch between the sender & receiver? Is something sending 7 bits with even parity, and the receiver set to 8 bits no parity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `System.Text.Encoding`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < evenParityASCII.Length; i++)
{
    evenParityASCII[i] = (byte)(evenParityASCII[i] & 0x7F);
}
string myAscii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(evenParityASCII);
```